# What are the best PDC 2008 videos that I need to look at?

Tags: pdc2008, pdc

Considering the full list of PDC videos published [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/pdc2008/RSS/Default.aspx) what are, in your opinion, the best session to download and see, considering their relevance to your work, technology and so on? Pleas, one session per answer (exception only for the sessions split in two parts) and please vote it so to move the best ones to the top.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807862/what-news-talk-from-the-microsoft-pdc-2009-will-have-the-most-effect-on-you-as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have to say that my favorite session was the "future of C#" video, very nice to be able to see what is coming in the future for C# and the .NET framework.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselmans

**Microsoft .NET Framework: Overview and Applications for Babies** http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL49/

Answer (score 1):

For me the best session was the [Mono](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC54/) one, really worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I realy enjoyed watching [A Lap Around VSTS 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL47/). But the [C# IDE tips and tricks](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL46/) session is my favourite of those I've watched so far. I shows a lot of simple short-cuts and tools that make your every day life a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think my favourite was the Parallel Programming one

Parallel Programming
http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL26/

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the ones about "Velocity". I found them really interesting when I was there, but if you're not interested in that, you should also check out the ones targeted at parallelism.

**Velocity sessions:** http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/pdc2008.velocity/

**Paralellism sessions:** http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/pdc2008.parallelism/

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing thread parallel work: 
TL58 Research: Concurrency Analysis Platform and Tools for Finding Concurrency Bugs 
and
TL55 The Concurrency and Coordination Runtime and Decentralized Software Services Toolkit

Finally progress towards deterministic testing and debugging of concurrent programs.