# What news/talk from the Microsoft PDC (2009) will have the most effect on you as a programmer?

Tags: .net, pdc

*(I have made this a community wiki)*

As a programmer that mostly works with .NET, the feature direction of the Microsoft development platforms have a great effect on my feature work.

The recent PDC gives an insight into where Microsoft is going with it’s development platforms.

- So what from the PDC do you consider will have the most effect on **you** as a programmer?
- When do you expect the above to start to effect “real life” programming?

Please provide links to the video of the talk and/ or transcript and/or related Channel 9 video and keep each answer to one area of technology.  Please explain way the 
technology will *affect you as a programmer* as well as saying giving a **short** overview of the technology.

see also:

- [Are the PDC 2009 videos released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754766/are-the-pdc-2009-videos-released)?
- [What are the best PDC 2008 videos that I need to look at?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277510/what-are-the-best-pdc-2008-videos-that-i-need-to-look-at)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft seems to be solving problems that I don't have and dreaming dreams that have no relevance to me personally.  That's okay with me, I still love and use the .NET Framework every day.

The best thing that seemed to come from the 2009 PDC was the free tablet PC that all attendees received.

To answer the question, I think the biggest news for me personally is that Microsoft isn't in touch with what I'm looking for them to help with.  When they spend so much time discussing Azure, when less than 1% of software applications (yes, I made that number up) need the scalability and features that Azure provides, I start looking elsewhere for help.